# Vue-Router: $router.go(-1) doesn't work in Safari

Tags: safari, vue.js, navigation, vue-router, html5-history

I have the following setup in the `App.vue`:

```
<top-nav></top-nav>
<main>
    <router-view v-bind="{isOnline}"></router-view>
</main>
```

And in the `top-nav`'s js I have the `goBack` method:

```
methods: {
    goBack() {
        this.$router.go(-1);
    },
    ...
},
```

This works just fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer, not Safari though. When debugging and setting a breakpoint on that `.go(-1)`-line it hits the breakpoint and everything looks fine (nothing undefined). The navigation call isn't done though.

This doesn't work on mobile nor desktop. I thought Safari had support for the History API?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/163/) works in Safari for me. Please provide a complete reproducible example.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I just set up a new vue project with the webpack template. It works fine in all browsers. Is it possible that the code from the question doesn't work because `top-nav` is a custom component and not just some html with bindings?

Comment: [No](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/164/). The fact that it is working in other browsers but not Safari means something funky is happening. Unless you can provide a fiddle that I can debug there isn't much more I can do. How is `goBack()` being called? Is it inside a `<form>`? I need more info. The bug is probably caused by code you have not provided in the question.

Comment: Ok so I just saw that the icon I'm using is wrapped in an anchor tag which has the `href` attribute set to '#', something I forgot to pull out of the designer's code. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the icon I used for going back was wrapped in an anchor tag with a set `href` attribute.

```
<a v-if="showBackButton" href="#" @click="goBack">
    <i class="icon icon-200-chevron-left-small"></i>
    <p>back</p>
</a>
```

### Solution:

Change the anchor tag to a span or something and of course remove the href attribute.